# Ruby - divmod is returning the correct value, but i'm not understanding why

Tags: ruby, integer, roman-numerals

I am working on the coding kata Roman Numerals defined [here](http://vimeo.com/channels/katacasts/7253727). While I have finished it and am not stuck I do have a question that I need help answering.

Here is where my question sits:

```
class Fixnum
  NUMERALS = [
    ['V', 5], ['IV', 4], ['I', 1]
  ]
  def to_roman
    roman = ""
    number = self
    for key, value in NUMERALS
      count, number = number.divmod(value)
      roman << (key * count)
    end
    roman
  end
end
```

When I execute divmod on say the number 5, like so

```
5.to_roman
```

It returns V. And that makes sense because

```
5.divmod(5) => 1, 0
```

But how does this code above not do the same with

```
5.divmod(1) => 5, 0
```

So how is it returning V and not IIIII, since it's just appending the key (I) times count (5). Somehow it's obviously correctly returning V instead of IIIII but i'm not sure where that logic is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never executes `5.divmod(1)`. The first time it executes the loop, `key` is 'V' and `value` is 5. It then executes `5.divmod(5)` and afterwards, `number == 0`. So in the next iteration of the loop, when `key` is 'IV' and `value` is 4, it executes `0.divmod(4)`, resulting in `count == 0` and nothing being added to the string.

But this code is weird, because `9.to_roman` returns 'VIV'.

Comment: Ah yes it never resets number. For some reason I wasn't taking that into account, I should have thought of that. yeah this code isn't complete by any means. It's a kata to demonstrate Test Driven Development with the red green cycle, only doing the basic thing to get the tests to pass. So this one is only doing 1-8.